# Converting special JSON response using retrofit

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to convert a specific JSON object that has a variable amount of subobjects, feks:

```
{
   name: 'Lars Monsen'
   id: 192492384
   accounts: {
        testaccount: {...}
        testaccount2: {...}
        ....
   }
}
```

So its easy to convert all the fields except for accounts. Since I don't know how many accounts each person has and accounts isn't a list. How can I map this info as an object?

The objects inside the account objects are the same. But since accounts not a list and the names of the accounts varies, I don't know how to map this properly.

Is it possible to write a specific converter for just accounts? I tried to write a specific converter but that ended up only the whole object.

Comment: Do testaccount and testaccount2 have the same values ?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak yes they have the same subtypes, child objects, children types, 'values', what ever you want to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `accounts` is a JS object with a fixed value type, why not use a **Map** with fixed value type? Like so

```
class Data {
    String name;
    int id;
    Map<String, Account> accounts;
}

class Account {
    ...
}
```

Just tested it with Gson, and it works. The map generated by Gson is even a LinkedHashMap, so the order of entries is preserved.

Comment: I want to upvote both answers but this won the simplicity contest!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Response {
    String name;
    long id;
    List<Account> accounts;
}

// ..

public class AccountsConverter implements JsonDeserializer<List<Account>> {
    public List<Account> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext ctx) {
        List<Account> vals = new ArrayList<Account>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
            Account account = ctx.deserialize(entry.getValue(), Account.class);
            account.setName(entry.getKey());
            vals.add(account);
        }
        return vals;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I implemented a custom converter for `List<Account>`, even though `account` in your json is actually an object. I iterate over every entry (key-value pair) in this `JsonObject` and `deserialize` the value. After that I append the key to the `account` instance using a setter.

To properly register this converter use this:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<List<Account>>(){}.getType(), new AccountsConverter());
```

Comment: For which object type would you register the converter with the GsonBuilder? I failed with `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new AccountsConverter()).create();` and other variants, replacing `Object.class` by some other types.

Comment: I succeeded registering the converter with `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<List<Account>>(){}.getType(), new AccountsConverter()).create();`. It leaves other `List` attributes (should you have any) to the default converter, but will try to deserialize every `List<Account>` from a JSON object.

Comment: @ChristianSemrau yes, you're right about the registering. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I want to upvote both answers but the other was the simplest one!